# How to get Antecedents/Consequents from FPGrowth Algorithm in Pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, fpgrowth

How am I misusing/misreading the use of the FPGrowth algorithm in Pyspark, I have a Apriori algorithm output I was hoping to be the same. Provided is my FPGrowth code, my Apriori output, and my FPGrowth output.

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\marka\\Downloads\\Assig2.txt")
data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split())
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split('\t'))
#notempty = transactions.map(lambda x: x is not '')
unique = transactions.map(lambda x: list(set(x))).cache()
model = FPGrowth.train(unique, minSupport=0.7, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

Apriori output:
[image]

FPGrowth output:

[image]

Am I misinterpreting the results or is there another way to output FPGrowth to be able to interpret the results like the Apriori?

To test, I used Weka for FPGrowth and got results similar to Apriori, so indication is my Pyspark output method is incorrect but documentation is always for fi in result: print(fi) so I'm unsure how.

Weka FPGrowth output:
[image]

Comment: This is not Python, but *pyspark* (edited accordingly tags & title)